# Is it possible to set a min/max for margin or padding in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'd like a 'flexible' margin or padding, similar to how iOS supports greater than or equal, less than or equal, or equal constants for their constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind margin / padding with a variable that is computed before the render, given the screen size.

Comment: Not _exactly_ what I'm looking for, but I think it's as close as I can get without a rendering engine to calculate it for you (e.g. AutoLayout).

Comment: out of the box!!